# How to create multiple scripts with name and content following a pattern

Tags: shell, scripting

I have a file containing some text, eg: text.txt:

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
```

and I want to make a script that creates a file with name format `name_of_file_value1_python.py` that contains the following lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6

url = "http://example.com/abc/get?value=value1"
print "count.value1",data['total']
```

Comment: Do you want just for the 1st value or all the values in the file `text.txt`

Comment: thank for reply, Yanivx. value1 will create a file name_of_file_value1_python.py that contain #!/usr/bin/python2.6

url = "http://example.com/abc/get?value=value1"
print "count.value1",data['total']

and value2 will create name_of_file_value2_python.py that containing #!/usr/bin/python2.6

url = "http://example.com/abc/get?value=value2"
print "count.value2",data['total']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while read i; do printf '#!/usr/bin/python2.6\n\nurl = "http://example.com/abc/get?value='$i'"\nprint "count.'$i'",data["total"]' > name_of_file_${i}_python.py; done < text.txt
```